# Get updated post meta on save_post action?

Tags: post-meta, actions, wpdb, save-post

I'm trying to save post id and keyword (Yoast Focus Keyword) to a custom table when post is created or updated via `save_post` action. It saves everything fine on Publish (first-time) but when I update the post, it gets old value for focus keyword from database and doesn't save the new value.

for example
Focus Keyword (Publish) = "Hello World" (works fine and keyword is stored properly)
Focus Keyword (1st Update) = "Hello" (Doesn't work and keeps "Hello World" in custom table)
Focus Keyword (2nd Update) = "Hello again" (It saves "Hello")

So basically the problem is that get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', true) returns which is already in the database and not the new value that is being saved.

What is the best way to get the new value while the post is being saved via `save_post` action?

$_POST['_yoast_wpseo_focuskw'] won't work because Yoast Focus Keyword input field doesn't have name set on input field. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox36u.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

This is my code.

```php
add_action('save_post', 'my_custom_table');
function my_custom_table($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "custom_table";

    $data = [
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'keyword' => get_post_meta( $post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', true )
    ];

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    } else {

        //check if new post so insert
        if( strpos( wp_get_raw_referer(), 'post-new' ) > 0 ) {

            if (get_post_status($post_id) === 'publish') {

                $wpdb->insert( 
                    $table_name, 
                    $data
                );

            }

        } else {

            $wpdb->update( 
                $table_name, 
                $data,
                array( 
                    'post_id' => $post_id
                ),
                array( '%d', '%s' ),
                array( '%d' )
            );
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress fires the [updated_{$meta_type}_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_meta_type_meta/) hook which fires after the metadata is updated.  In your case, the hook would be `updated_post_meta` and you could have your function run on that hook instead of the `save_post` hook.

Comment: Thanks. :) It's working.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on when `_yoast_wpseo_focuskw` is actually written/updated in the plugin you're working with. That's where I'd start. Try and track it down, is it being written on post_save as well? Or earlier? Probably later. Somewhere around `WPSEO_Meta::set_value()` [#](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/1e151dbd01c1f1484a5713223acbb69801c8174f/inc/class-wpseo-meta.php#L692), can backtrace from there.

Then adapt your code to that, queuing whatever you're doing *after* the new value has been written.