# Access NEW/UPDATED post values in save_post() callback function

Tags: save-post

I want to run a "background" function when a custom post type is saved (updated or created) using the NEW/UPDATED post values. The "background" function updates a taxonomy, based on a custom field in the custom post type.

How do I access the NEW/UPDATED post values? I'm obviously doing something dumb here but I've been at it two hours with no progress.

I thought `save_post()` was fired after the dbase updated but I only get "old" values.

For the avoidance of doubt, I am def calling the functions correctly:

```
function custom_post_type_callback($post_id) {
  //obvs the background function isn't defined here my actual code
  my_background_function($post_id){
     $my_variable = get_post($post_id); // <- this is always the "old" values
  };
}

add_action( 'save_post_custom_post_type', 'custom_post_type_callback' );
```

It works perfectly if I save the post AGAIN.

Comment: Oh, $^%. Is this because the custom_field is actually post_meta? Should I be using the updated_{$meta_type}_meta hook?

Comment: what is your background function doing? You can't retrieve this data from inside the other function, it's only available when the relevant hook is called, so you would need to save and store the data for when your function runs. Have you considered the updated post hooks instead? Yes, custom fields are just the user facing name of post meta

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I think this post is basically the same issue but they realised they were trying to update post_meta sooner than me! https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/396013/get-updated-post-meta-on-save-post-action

Comment: I think you need to share more context for what you're trying to do and why, as well as code that's much much closer to what you actually have. ( e.g. it's still unclear what you meant by a background function, is this from a PHP extension for threading? A cron job? Or did you just mean a separate function? ) Use the `Edit` link to update your question so that it's clearer and has more information